# how to use knownfolderid in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Want to make old script which pins shortcuts to taskbar compatible with Windows 10. Found that CSIDL used there is very old and newer method should be 
[KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx).

Original code uses this for example

```
Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = &H17
Set objAllUsersProgramsFolder = objShell.NameSpace(CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS)
```

Now, if i want to use

```
FOLDERID_UserPinned
```

in a similar way, where and how should i put it?

Comment: Try `objShell.NameSpace("shell:User Pinned")`. Check the full  list in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37172935/2165759)

Comment: Thanks, that will do.