# Folders path available too all users in diferents computers

Tags: windows, directory, path, shortcut

here's my problem, I'm doing an internship in a company and I was asked to find a way to make a shortcut in a folder that is in my Pc but I want it to work in any other computer.

To do so, I want to replace the `"C:/users/username/desktop/folder"` for a "Variable".

Than in every computer or user that i want to use this shortcut, I just have to say that "variable" means `"C:/users/username"` or `"D:/"` or wherever i put the folder in.

Answer (score 0):

This should already be happening automatically when you create the shortcut. Meaning, the [SpecialFolderDataBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/8833199d-fc03-4535-8011-ba36c4b3ad5f) entry (and the known folder entry) will exist and its base location is a non-computer specific folder id + a offset into the main id list for the user/computer specific part. EnvironmentVariableDataBlock also exists when applicable.

Because the .lnk format is documented, you could create a shortcut that only contains a EnvironmentVariableDataBlock for example if you really wanted to...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [How to create shortcut to Computer on the user's desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37172935/3080770)

---

You can try this vbscript to create a shortcut to `%userprofile%` on the Desktop :

Just open your **notepad** or your **notepad++** and save it as ***CreateShortcut.vbs***

---

```vbs
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    With .CreateShortcut(.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\User Profile.lnk")
        .TargetPath = "%userprofile%"
        .Description = "Open User Profile Folder"
        .Save
    End  With
End  With
```

Comment: There is any way to send, i dont know like a folder or pdf to someone with that solution, but like, something on C:\teste to E:\teste2 ?! @Hackoo